# Is it possible to avoid page scrolling when changing focus on HTML elements? (Using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

This may be a duplicated, can't tell, I searched but couldn't find a method or answer to avoid the scrolling of the page when using focus and JavaScript on an scenario like this one.

I am coding a little tool that searches in a DB and to make it more user-friendly I added the "show suggestions" feature. So when a user types in a seachbox and matches are found, it displays a dropdown with suggestions. A friend of mine asked me to add keyboard support to this dropdown (like an HTML dropdown list) and while trying with JavaScript to mimic the effect I came to this: http://jsfiddle.net/9jaazwxa/

However, when you type in the down or up arrow in the keyboard it also adds an undesired scroll behavior to the page.

Is it possible to avoid this?

HTML:

```js
var i = 0;
var itemnum = document.querySelectorAll('#navlist > ul > li');
var topval = itemnum.length;
var searchbox = document.getElementById('search-box');
var navlist = document.getElementById('navlist');
searchbox.addEventListener('keydown', showhidden, false);
searchbox.addEventListener('keydown', tabnav, true);
navlist.addEventListener('keydown', tabnav, true);

function showhidden(){
  document.getElementById('navlist').style.display = "block";
}

function tabnav(event){
 switch(event.keyCode){
  case 40: //down arrow
   if(i < topval){
    i++;
    var activetab = document.getElementById('tab-' + i);
    activetab.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    activetab.focus();
        if(i > 1){
     var prevtab = document.getElementById('tab-' + (i-1));
     prevtab.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }            
   }
   
   else if(i > topval){
    i = 1;
    var activetab = document.getElementById('tab-' + i);
    activetab.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    activetab.focus();
        var prevtab = document.getElementById('tab-' + ( i + topval));
    prevtab.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";        
   }
  break;
  
  case 38: //up arrow
   if(i > 1){
    i--;
    var activetab = document.getElementById('tab-' + i);
    activetab.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    activetab.focus();        
    var prevtab = document.getElementById('tab-' + (i+1));
    prevtab.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";    
   }
 } 
}
```

```css
body{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 max-width:960px;
 margin:2em;
}

.short-parr{
 max-width:450px;
}

#navlist {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigate suggestion list</h2>

<form id="theForm" action="#" method="get">
 <label>Search box</label><br />
 <input id="search-box" type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off"/>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<h4>Suggestions</h4>
<div id="navlist">
 <ul>
  <li><a id="tab-1" href="#">1 tab option</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab-2" href="#">2 tab option</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab-3" href="#">3 tab option</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab-4" href="#">4 tab option</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<p class="short-parr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et utinam minimum pertinacia duo, ut laoreet invidunt maiestatis eum. Justo volutpat cu sit, quo quaeque fabulas consulatu an. Meliore phaedrum evertitur te pro, no eros elit magna pri. Ut unum ferri neglegentur duo.</p>

<p class="short-parr">Quis doming eloquentiam vix at, pro veri accumsan expetenda in. Mei id homero legimus. Ex idque omnium sit, aliquam consequuntur mel ei, mea enim virtute mandamus te. Nam in debitis denique dissentiet. Mei docendi accusam persecuti ea.</p>

<p class="short-parr">Vix corpora fierent cu, his et mutat omnesque, quodsi convenire at pri. Magna possit an eam. Paulo dolorem adversarium mei at, doctus omittam senserit ea per, vel congue voluptatibus id. Duo odio adversarium an, paulo graece persecuti his ex. Eum no viderer mentitum definiebas, duo affert reformidans et.</p>

<p class="short-parr">Usu cu recusabo mediocrem, ius ea falli facilisis molestiae. His postea graeci adversarium eu, in dicit putent mollis pri. Quo errem alienum appellantur eu, eu pro blandit copiosae. Ut vis nibh labitur delicata, ex nihil assueverit vim, est novum causae nonumes cu.</p>

<p class="short-parr">Eos id altera sensibus dissentiunt, nec ei consul salutatus. Ius at atqui nemore. Ne esse laoreet vis. Cetero euismod volutpat eum cu. Ut delenit alienum nominavi qui, solet nominavi qui ex. Mea graecis incorrupte ne, vis iisque suscipiantur ei.</p>
```

Comment: The "live" tool is more stylish, but this is the main idea

Comment: event.preventDefault() immediately inside your tabnav function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add prevent default:

```
function tabnav(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  .
```

Of course insert it into the 'case arrow down/up' otherwise you won't have any input at all

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was looking to the wrong side trying something like "scrollTo"

Comment: We all need a push to the right direction now and then ;)